# junit 3 multiple arguments

Tags: java, junit

need some help with Junit testing.
I have a method as follows..

```
public static boolean updateBook(int id, String name, String author,
            String libraryNum, String isbn, String refNum, String year)
```

It does an update on a database table but I need to test that the String arguments are greater than 1 and less than 21 characters. Struggling to find the right documentation to help me. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public void test0003(){
        DaoBook testObject = new DaoBook();
        try {
            assertEquals(true, testObject.updateBook(1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?));
        } catch (DaoBookExceptionHandler e) {
            fail("Should not reach here ... no exception expected");
        }
    }
```

What could I put in for the question marks above that would test that the String contains at least 1 character?

```
public void test0004() {
        DaoBook testObject = new DaoBook();
        try {
            assertEquals(true, testObject.updateBook(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ?,
?, ?, ?, ?, ?));
        } catch (DaoBookExceptionHandler e) {
            fail("Should not reach here ... no exception expected");
        }
    }
```

Similarly here, what could I put in for the question marks that would test that the strings are not greater than 21 characters?

Thanks in advance for help. Sorry if I am being vague, first time user

Comment: Where is a problem? You don't know what you have to put into `?` ? It external code or yours?

Comment: Are you really sure hat you want to do the test in JUnit? JUnit tests if your code is working, not if your values are correct. You can test if any validation in your DAO works, so just put an empty string or null, or a string longer than 21 characters in your test.

Comment: *String arguments are greater than 1 and less than 21 characters* ..do you want to test the length of the arguments? Or do you want to test how does `updateBook` execute when the length of any of the string args is out of your expected range?

Answer (score 0):

For each parameter make 2 tests: one with empty string, the other one with a string longer than 21 char.

For example for the 'name' param

```
public void test_NameEmpty() {
    DaoBook testObject = new DaoBook();
    try {
        assertEquals(true, testObject.updateBook(1, "", "valid", "valid", "valid", "valid", "valid"));
    } catch (DaoBookExceptionHandler e) {
        fail("Should not reach here ... no exception expected");
    }
}

public void test_NameTooLong() {
    DaoBook testObject = new DaoBook();
    try {
        assertEquals(true, testObject.updateBook(1, "0123456789012345678901", "valid", "valid", "valid", "valid", "valid"));
    } catch (DaoBookExceptionHandler e) {
        fail("Should not reach here ... no exception expected");
    }
}
```

(etc for each string param)